# Search for a string in an array through SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named '*offers*' that has a column `in_stores`. It contains the ids of the stores that this offer is available in. Graphically this table looks like this:

```
id | title    | in_stores
1  | Shoes    | 1002,1003
2  | Gloves   | 1020,1011
3  | Shades   | 1002,1009
4  | Hats     | 1010,1002
5  | Shoes    | 1220
6  | Shirts   | 1010
7  | Hats     | 1002
```

Each value in `in_stores` is saved with the `implode()` function through PHP.

***My question:***
How to select in a single `mysqli` query all the offers that are available in a store with id 1002. In this example the query should return offers with id 1,3,4,7. I guess I should use something like explode() first to get the results in an array and than in_array() to search for the specific id in it but all those functions are unavailable within SQL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Comment: Comma separated values that you need to search are a very bad idea. Is it too late to change your design to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a major issue with storing comma separated fields.

MySQL does have a function to allow searching for these, and this will be a lot more reliable than trying to rely on using LIKE. But as it still cannot effectively use any index it will not be fast.

```
SELECT *
FROM offers
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1002', in_stores)
```

Far better to redesign your database to use an extra table with a row for each value for each id.

Comment: I understand the better way of doing things. Just out of curiosity will this function always work the way I want it unlike when using `LIKE` with numbers greater than 9999? Despite the slowness? It catches the field as an array and that searches it?

Comment: Not sure how it works under the covers, but it is designed to find values in comma separated lists reliably. The general problem comes when the list is not comma separated, or uses a comma AND a space. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: Yeah. But in my case I strictly use comma separated values with no possible way of adding a space. I am chosing you answer as the correct one since it is the exact answer to what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

You "could" do it with a `LIKE` Query, but this is not recommended.

`SELECT * FROM offers WHERE in_stores LIKE "%1002%"`.

As long as you don't have values bigger than 9999 this will work.
**BUT** when one of your stores has the id `11002` of `99991002` it will also return these unwanted values.

What you should do is transform your mysql table to a have a second table `storeLocations` or sth. else. This should only have the properties `offer_id` and `store_id`.
It will transform your data to:

```
`offers`
id | title   
1  | Shoes    
2  | Gloves  
3  | Shades   
4  | Hats    
5  | Shoes   
6  | Shirts  
7  | Hats    

`storeLocations`
offer_id, store_id
1        | 1002
1        | 1003
2        | 1020
2        | 1011
3        | 1002
3        | 1009
4        | 1010
4        | 1002
5        | 1220
6        | 1010
7        | 1002
```

Then you can select from it like

```
SELECT * FROM offers AS o 
   LEFT JOIN storeLocations as l ON (o.id=l.offer_id) 
   WHERE l.store_id = 1002;
```

Now when you insert data you don't have to use implode but insert as many rows into `storeLocations` as there are store_id's for that specific item.

For more info on that topic have a look [here](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/An-Introduction-to-Database-Normalization/).

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be using the MySQL `LIKE` operator. It searches the database column for strings specified in your query.

Try this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM offers WHERE in_store LIKE  '%1002%'";
```

Check this link for more explanation:  [W3Schools - SQL LIKE Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_like.asp)

I think that should do the trick.